# Normalizing deeply nested Json data for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

I am new to working with pandas, and I am having difficulty extracting the data for color variations from a series of makeup products.

My goal is to set up a dataframe with all color variations for each product in their own lists.

Something along these lines:

| Name | Type | URL | Price | Description | Images | Shades | Hex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product1 | lipstick | ... | 27.00 | ... | [.,.,.] | [.,.,.] | [.,.] |

[I am trying to flatten this data, but I keep receiving key errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds2jU.png)

Here is the initial request.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'authority': 'ncsa.sdapi.io',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'authorizationtoken': 'Mi1tYy11cy1lbi1lY29tbXYxOmh0dHBzOi8vbS5tYWNjb3NtZXRpY3MuY29t',
    'business-unit': '2-mc-us-en-ecommv1',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'clientid': 'stardust-fe-client',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://m.maccosmetics.com',
    'referer': 'https://m.maccosmetics.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Android"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36',
}

json_data = {
    'query': '{\n                products(environment: {prod:true},\n                    filter: [{tags:{filter:{key:{in:["lipstick"]}},includeInnerHits:false}}],\n                    sort: [{tags:{product_display_order:ASCENDING}}]\n                ) {\n                    \n        ... product__collection \n        \n        items {\n            ... product_default ... product_productSkinType ... product_form ... product_productCoverage ... product_benefit ... product_productReview ... product_skinConcern ... product_usage ... product_productFinish ... product_usageOptions ... product_brushTypes ... product_brushShapes \n            skus {\n                total\n                items {\n                    ... product__skus_default ... product__skus_autoReplenish ... product__skus_colorFamily ... product__skus_skuLargeImages ... product__skus_skuMediumImages ... product__skus_skuSmallImages ... product__skus_vtoFoundation ... product__skus_vtoMakeup \n                }\n            }\n        }\n    \n    \n                }\n            }\n\nfragment product__collection \n    on product_collection {\n        items {\n            product_id\n            skus {\n                items {\n                    inventory_status\n                    sku_id\n                }\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_default \n    on product {\n        default_category {\n            id\n            value\n        }\n        description\n        display_name\n        is_hazmat\n        meta {\n            description\n        }\n        product_badge\n        product_id\n        product_url\n        short_description\n        tags {\n            total\n            items {\n                id\n                value\n                key\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_productSkinType \n    on product {\n        skin {\n            type {\n                key\n                value\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_form \n    on product {\n        form {\n            key\n            value\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_productCoverage \n    on product {\n        coverage {\n            key\n            value\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_benefit \n    on product {\n        benefit {\n            benefits {\n                key\n                value\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_productReview \n    on product {\n        reviews {\n            average_rating\n            number_of_reviews\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_skinConcern \n    on product {\n        skin {\n            concern {\n                key\n                value\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_usage \n    on product {\n        usage {\n            content\n            label\n            type\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_productFinish \n    on product {\n        finish {\n            key\n            value\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_usageOptions \n    on product {\n        usage_options {\n            key\n            value\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_brushTypes \n    on product {\n        brush {\n            types {\n                key\n                value\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product_brushShapes \n    on product {\n        brush {\n            shapes {\n                key\n                value\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product__skus_default \n    on product__skus {\n        is_default_sku\n        is_discountable\n        is_giftwrap\n        is_under_weight_hazmat\n        iln_listing\n        iln_version_number\n        inventory_status\n        material_code\n        prices {\n            currency\n            is_discounted\n            include_tax {\n                price\n                original_price\n                price_per_unit\n                price_formatted\n                original_price_formatted\n                price_per_unit_formatted\n            }\n        }\n        sizes {\n            value\n            key\n        }\n        shades {\n            name\n            description\n            hex_val\n        }\n        sku_id\n        sku_badge\n        unit_size_formatted\n        upc\n    }\n\n\nfragment product__skus_autoReplenish \n    on product__skus {\n        is_replenishable\n    }\n\n\nfragment product__skus_colorFamily \n    on product__skus {\n        color_family {\n            key\n            value\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product__skus_skuLargeImages \n    on product__skus {\n        media {\n            large {\n                src\n                alt\n                height\n                width\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product__skus_skuMediumImages \n    on product__skus {\n        media {\n            medium {\n                src\n                alt\n                height\n                width\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product__skus_skuSmallImages \n    on product__skus {\n        media {\n            small {\n                src\n                alt\n                height\n                width\n            }\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product__skus_vtoFoundation \n    on product__skus {\n        vto {\n            is_foundation_experience\n        }\n    }\n\n\nfragment product__skus_vtoMakeup \n    on product__skus {\n        vto {\n            is_color_experience\n        }\n    }\n',
    'variables': {},
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://ncsa.sdapi.io/stardust-prodcat-product-v3/graphql/core/v1/extension/v1',
    headers=headers,
    json=json_data,
)
```

All of these values returned as expected

```
json_object = response.json()

result_items = json_object['data']['products']['items']


result_items[0]['skus']['items'][0]['prices'][0]['include_tax']['price_formatted']

result_items[0]['skus']['items'][0]['shades']

result_items[0]['skus']['items'][0]['media']['large'][0]['src']

result_items[0]['skus']['items'][0]['media']['large'][0]['alt']

result_items[0]['skus']['items'][0]['color_family'][0]['value']
```

I was able to access the shade names for a single product like so

```
shade_list = []
def get_shade_names():
    items = result_items[0]['skus']['items']
    for item in items:
        shades = item['shades']
        for shade_data in shades:
            shade = shade_data['name']
            shade_list.append(shade)

get_shade_names()
print(shade_list)
```

but several attempts at implementing the nested loop for the list of lists has just resulted in a single list or a series of errors.

This is when I pivoted from DataFrame to json_normalize. However, I keep receiving key errors when trying to use record path and meta.

Can someone show me how to proceed? I tried to go off of the examples in the pandas documentation, but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An example using meta and record_path:

```
data = response.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data["data"]["products"]["items"],
    meta="product_id",
    record_path=["skus", "items", "shades"]
)
```

Select a product:

```
shades = df.query("product_id.eq('99908')")["name"].to_list()
print(shades)
```

Output:

```
['Marrakesh-mere', 'Sheer Outrage', 'Dubonnet Buzz', 'Mull It Over', 'Rose Mary', 'Sweet Cinnamon', 'Devoted To Chili', 'Wild Rebel', 'Devoted To Danger', 'Love Clove', 'Ruby New', 'Gingerella', 'Stay Curious', 'Peppery Pink', 'All-Star Anise', 'Nice Spice', 'Spice World', 'Over The Taupe', 'Brickthrough', 'Nutmeg Ganache', 'Sorry Not Sorry', 'Pumpkin Spiced', 'Hot Paprika']
```

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple dataframes
Your output is not really clear but you can use something like:

```
# Extract base data from top level records
main_cols = ['product_id', 'display_name', 'description']
main_df = pd.json_normalize(result_items)[main_cols]

# Extract sub dataset
shade_df = pd.json_normalize(result_items, ['skus', 'items', 'shades'], 'product_id', record_prefix='shade.')

# Merge base and other sub dataset
df = main_df.merge(shade_df, on='product_id')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    product_id                        display_name                                        description            shade.name     shade.description shade.hex_val
0        99908  Powder Kiss Velvet Blur Slim Stick  Experience moisture-matte to the max with our ...        Marrakesh-mere  Intense orange brown       #b0594d
1        99908  Powder Kiss Velvet Blur Slim Stick  Experience moisture-matte to the max with our ...         Sheer Outrage       Grapefruit pink       #ca5a5a
2        99908  Powder Kiss Velvet Blur Slim Stick  Experience moisture-matte to the max with our ...         Dubonnet Buzz         Deep red wine       #c95c54
3        99908  Powder Kiss Velvet Blur Slim Stick  Experience moisture-matte to the max with our ...          Mull It Over           Dirty peach       #a45f51
4        99908  Powder Kiss Velvet Blur Slim Stick  Experience moisture-matte to the max with our ...             Rose Mary            Soft mauve       #b96161
..         ...                                 ...                                                ...                   ...                   ...           ...
329      19393                      Lipmix / Satin  Lipmix is to the makeup artist as tubes of pai...                 Satin                             #dedede
330       1625                           Lip Erase  M·A·C Pro Lip Erase is a professional product ...                  Pale                   N27       #e3bd92
331      19392                      Lipmix / Gloss  Lipmix is to the makeup artist as tubes of pai...                 Gloss                             #dfdbcb
332      82134         Lipstick / Frosted Firework  A blast of five holiday-exclusive Lustre, Fros...  Once Bitten, Ice Shy  Sheer white w/ pearl       #eae8df
333      52596                     Lustre Lipstick  M·A·C Lipstick – the iconic product that made ...              Lady Bug         Yellow tomato       #b23532
```